# unSelectCancel does not accept CSS selector :not()

Tags: css, css-selectors, fullcalendar

I am attempting to exclude the child of a div in the unselectCancel string. And although the docs say it accepts the CSS Selectors it is not excluding the dismiss button which is embedded in my flyout.

```
unselectCancel={".quick-event-editor-flyout:not(.dismiss-button)"}
```

I have verified that the dismiss-button is directly embedded in the flyout div. And have attempted to use the universal selectors as well.

Comment: That selector selects an element that is a flyout and not a dismiss button. If you want it to select **children** of the flyout that are not dismiss buttons, use the child combinator: `>` to make it so: `.quick-event-editor-flyout > :not(.dismiss-button)`.